Show that composition of analytic functions is analytic without using holomorphicity
suppose $f$ is analytic at $w_0$ and $g$ is analytic at $z_0$ and $g(z_0)=w_0$, show that $f\circ g$ is analytic at $z_0$ without using the fact that holomorphicity implies analyticity (the converse can be used, however)
My idea was to express $f$ and $g$ as infinite sums and then show that there exists a sequence $a_n$ such that $f(g(z))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$, however I found that the derivation is quite complicated.
